# Component is not re-rendering on form submission. It only re-renders on a full page refresh

Tags: reactjs, axios, rails-api

To summarize, I am submitting a POST request VIA axios and I am having the hardest time figuring out why it will not re-render my component that is displaying the newly added data (Where all of this is taking place).

Here is my post request (data is persisting correctly):

```
addNewLoad = (pickup_date, pickup_location, rate, delivery_date, delivery_location, loaded_miles, deadhead_miles, local, delivery_id) => {
        let config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', "Accepts": "application/json",
            }
        }
     const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001'})
      instance.post('/api/v1/pickup_deliveries', { pickup_date, pickup_location, rate, delivery_date, delivery_location, loaded_miles, deadhead_miles, local, delivery_id}, config)
        .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
          const pickup_deliveries = [ ...this.state.pickup_deliveries, response.data ]
          this.setState({pickup_deliveries})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Here is my component's state:

```
    state = {
        fiveDayView: [new Date(),
        addDays(new Date(), 1),
        addDays(new Date(), 2),
        addDays(new Date(), 3),
        addDays(new Date(), 4)],
        routeId: '',
        show: false,
        pickup_deliveries: [],
    }
```

So.. when I `this.setState({pickup_deliveries})`, I would expect my component to re-render.  Not only that but within this component, I am currently pulling all the data from my Rails API and using said data to display within that component.  I figured between the `this.setState({pickup_deliveries})` and the re-rendering of the parent component where this data is coming from as `this.props.apiData`, there would be no issue with my component re-rendering and displaying the newly submitted data.

Sorry if that is confusing but I am at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all is to check that you are not getting an empty array from the API, (check network tab). In that case you are not actually changing the array, but running a setState with the same value...

setState doesn't re-render if there was no state change detected

**Second** important thing when you update a state and use old value of the state you shouldn't access this.state, your code should look smth like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  pickup_deliveries: [...prevState.pickup_deliveries, response.data]);
```

Because state updates are async so you should never depend on this.state while updating state, as you  might get an older state than the one you want to update.

More on this topic https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
Quoting:

> **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**
>
> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

**Third** (**workaround**) to keep in mind in general is a workaround by add a parameter like 'lastRequestTimestamp' to the state to force state changes, specially when you are dealing with updating arrays or objects in state, this workaround is just to prove to yourself you are mutating the array which is not a state change as the array reference is still the same, **but you shouldn't use this workaround except for debugging...**

Comment: Very nice comment!  And number one applied to me and I was curious as to why.  The array is ALWAYS empty...

Comment: Glad you found it useful, note that second issue also applies to your code, you just don't see it's effect because the API request is slowed than the async state update. but in general it's a good practice not to access this.state values when you are going to pass them to setState

Comment: So, does that mean I need to do it in a lifecycle method since prev state is associated with componentWillReceiveProps().  Also, does the empty array fix require any back end tweaking?  Sorry I am bombarding you.

Comment: no, this.setState accepts either an object or a function that returns an object, if it's a function setState will pass prevState to it, so no need to put the setState in lifecycle methods...

Comment: regarding backend tweaking this depends on your requirement, if you want the new pickup delivery to come from the API then the post request should return the object created, otherwise you can assume that since the api returned success the object was created then you just create an array from the parameters you already passed to the API

Comment: Ideally you should test your API with postman or cURL first before trying to work on the frontend app so you don't endup with situations in which you are not sure which part is not working

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
this.setState({ pickup_deliveries });
```

to

```
this.setState(() => ({ pickup_deliveries }));
```

for callback based `setState`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still does not re-render the component.  But, as I said, the data post fine to the component on a full refresh.  It's a fairly annoying little problem :(